# Check if user is logged in aws cognito, JAVA

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am using Java as back end to communicate with AWS Cognito. I am able to login, logout, create users, sign out and other functions. I am also able to verify an access token by following this [link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-user-pools-using-tokens-with-identity-providers.html):

But I want to verify if a user is logged in or not. 
In JAVA, is there a isLoggedin() function that returns a boolean or is there a way to see if the token is revoked? These functions exist for Android and iOS but what about JAVA.

I thought this verifies if the token is active, but it only verifies if the token is in the right format:

```
    // This parses token to JWT.
    JWT jwtparser = JWTParser.parse(accessToken);
    String JWTissuer = jwtparser.getJWTClaimsSet().getIssuer(); 
    JWSHeader header = (JWSHeader) jwtparser.getHeader(); 
    Object token_use = jwtparser.getJWTClaimsSet().getClaim("token_use"); 
    Object exp = jwtparser.getJWTClaimsSet().getClaim("iat");
    Date expirationDate = jwtparser.getJWTClaimsSet().getExpirationTime(); 

    // Read in JSON Key file saved somewhere safe
    File file = new File("jwks.json");
    String content = FileUtils.readFileToString(file, "utf-8");
    JSONObject JsonObjects = new JSONObject(content);
    JSONArray keysArray = JsonObjects.getJSONArray("keys");
    JSONObject keyString = (JSONObject) keysArray.get(1);

    if (header.getKeyID().equals(keyString.get("kid")) && token_use.toString().equals("access") && JWTissuer.equals("https://cognito-idp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/us-west-2_xxxxxxx")) {
        return true;
    } else { return false; }
```

I want to see if a user is logged in. I have not found an appropriate method to do so.

Mahalo

Comment: Welcome to SO, Please provide some code or at least an approach you tried to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a work around:

```
    public boolean isLoggedin(String accessToken) {
        GetUserRequest request = new GetUserRequest();
        request.withAccessToken(accessToken);

        AWSCognitoIdentityProviderClientBuilder builder = 
               AWSCognitoIdentityProviderClientBuilder.standard();
        builder.withRegion("us-west-2");
        AWSCognitoIdentityProvider cognitoCreate = builder.build();

        GetUserResult result = cognitoCreate.getUser(request);

        try {
            System.out.println("success");
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.getMessage();
            return false;
        }
    }
```